# Django: Saving created object to user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model of uploads and i want to associate the uploaded images to the user so that later each user can only view his objects so  so i m trying to save the created objects to the authenticated user, but it's not working and i keep getting owner =null on my model

```js
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def Upload_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Uploads.objects.all()
        uploads=queryset.filter(owner=request.user)
        serializer = UploadSerializer(uploads, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=request.user)
                respFile=list(File.objects.filter(id=str(File.objects.latest('created_at'))))
            return Response(respFile)
            
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Edit : i think the problem is in the Post request itself it is not overriding the default method therefore the changes i apply do not work any idea how to change the post method ?**

Comment: i tried but it is giving me the same result, i think the problem is the POST request itself no matter how i change it or change the response it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Rihab can you add the traceback

Comment: i fixed it, as i suspected it was the Post request, however now the filtering doesn't work with a function based view , i updated the code if you kindly could check with me

Comment: i have also solved that so thank you

Comment: do you still have any error of every thing work fine now

Comment: i m trying to send a file as a response for my post request but i m getting an error : file object is not json serializable, i updated the code it you want to check

Comment: JSON notation has only a handful of native datatypes (objects, arrays, strings, numbers, booleans, and null), so anything serialized in JSON needs to be expressed as one of these types. so you have to use json encoder and json decoder

Comment: I see it worked after i serialized the response, thank you a lot for helping me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class IsOwnerFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        queryset=Uploads.objects.all()
        return queryset.filter(owner=request.user)

class UploadView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Uploads.objects.all()
    serializer_class=UploadSerializer
    filter_backends = (IsOwnerFilterBackend,)
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def methodes(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.method=='POST':
            serializer=UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(owner=request.user)   
                return Response("test_token success", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)   
            return HttpResponse({'message':'error'},status=400)
        elif request.method=='GET': 
                images=Uploads.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
                serializers=UploadSerializer(images[0],many=False)
                return JsonResponse(serializers.data,safe=False)
```